# Why might dropdownlist.SelectedIndex = value fail?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that I am binding to a datatable.  Here is the code I am using to do it:

```
ddlBuildAddr.DataSource = buildings
ddlBuildAddr.DataTextField = "buildingName"
ddlBuildAddr.DataValueField = "buildingId"
Dim addressId As Int32 = OfficeData.GetInstance().GetBuildingId(currentAddress)
ddlBuildAddr.SelectedIndex = addressId
ddlBuildAddr.DataBind()
```

Unfortunately, the line `ddlBuildAddr.SelectedIndex = addressId` is failing.  Looking at this line through the debugger, the `SelectedIndex` goes to -1, while `addressId` goes to 2.  What  gives?  Why would the assignment operator flatout not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your ddlDeptName.DataBind() to before you try to set the selected index.  Before you bind, you don't actually have any items in the dropdown so an index of 2 is invalid.

Comment: Stupid mistake, you are right!  However, the selectedindex stil does not change.

Comment: Have you verified that the dropdown is actually getting filled with anything?  Try commenting out the line to set the index and verify that there are items being loaded into the list.  Also, as others have suggested, you probably want to set the SelectedValue property.

Comment: Argh - missed the DataBind() call. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
ddlDeptName.SelectedIndex = addressId
```

With this:

```
ddlDeptName.SelectedValue = addressId.ToString()
```

As for why it's failing - addressId is likely out of the range of possible **index** values of your drop down list.

Comment: If you take the ToString, then you come up with exactly the same thing that I suggested, which you said it did not work... huh?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set the `SelectedValue` property instead.

Comment: SelectedValue is returning an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

as TLiebe has pointed out, move your databind to BEFORE you try to set the selected. the databinding method basically wipes out any previous state you have set on the combo-box.

second, the selected index is NOT the datavalue or the selected value members. it is the index of the ListItem in the dropdown's collection of items such that dropdown[ dropdown.selectedindex] will give you the item from the list that is marked as selected. so, you must find the item you want to select, then set the selectedindex to the index of that item.

a VB example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt1bzx2b(VS.100).aspx):

```
' Selects the item whose text is Apples
ListBox1.Items.FindByText("Apples")
If Not li Is Nothing Then
   li.Selected = True
End If

// Selects the item whose text is Apples
ListItem li = ListBox1.Items.FindByText("Apples");
if(li != null)
{
   li.Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ddlBuildAddr.DataSource = buildings
ddlBuildAddr.DataTextField = "buildingName"
ddlBuildAddr.DataValueField = "buildingId"
Dim addressId As Int32 = OfficeData.GetInstance().GetBuildingId(currentAddress)

ddlBuildAddr.Databind()
```

After

```
foreach (var item in ddlBuildAddr.Items)
{
  if(Convert.toInt32(item.value)==addressId)
  {
     item.selected=true;
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows....

```
ddlBuildAddr.DataSource = buildings
ddlBuildAddr.DataTextField = "buildingName"
ddlBuildAddr.DataValueField = "buildingId"
ddlBuildAddr.DataBind()

Dim addressId As Int32 = OfficeData.GetInstance().GetBuildingId(currentAddress)

ddlBuildAddr.SelectedValue = addressId //It may throw error if item is not found in the list
(or)
ddlBuildAddr.Items.FindByValue(addressId).Selected = true;
(or)
ListItem lstNew = ddlBuildAddr.Items.FindByValue(addressId)
ddlBuildAddr.selectedItem = lstNew
```